# How do I contact the Consulate of Denmark in NYC?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, denmark, embassies, consulates

I've had my visa in processing for a month without any updates. Whenever I call the consulate and select the visa option from the automated voicemail, I'm redirected to VFS, which hasn't been helpful. I've also emailed the consulate without receiving a response.

How can I get in touch with them about my visa status?
Options:

- Can I call and select a different option, even if it's not related to visas? I know it might not be the proper approach, but I'm running out of alternatives.
- Should I attempt another email? Is there a chance they'll respond, considering they didn't reply to my initial email?
- Is reaching out to them on platforms like Twitter or Facebook considered appropriate?

Comment: According to another questions of yours (https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182858/visa-still-processing-at-dutch-embassy-in-new-york) it's the Dutch embassy that is processing visa. why do you want to ask the consulate of Denmark about it? (they are in the same building, but on different floors)

Comment: I made a mistake in the earlier post- didn't realise that Dutch Embassy meant Netherlands and not Denmark. The visa is in processing at the Denmark Consulate in New York